# Find all squarefree integers whose divisors $d_1 < d_2 < · · · < d_k$ satisfy $d_i − d_{i−1}|n$ for all $2 \leq i \leq k$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Disclaimer:**  this problem came from USAMTS: https://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_31_3.pdf

[The contest has ended.](https://www.usamts.org/Problems/U_Problems.php), in case there is any doubt.

Problem: Find all squarefree  integers whose divisors $d_1 < d_2 < · · · < d_k$ satisfy $d_i − d_{i−1}|n$ for all $2 \leq i \leq k$.

My thinking is if $d_i − d_{i−1}|n$ then $d_i − d_{i−1}$ is in $d_1, d_2,... d_k$. Then $d_2-d_1 < d_2$ is a divisor so $d_2-d_1 = d_1, d_2 = 2d_1$. Obviously $d_1 = 1$ and $d_2 = 2$ since $1 | n$.

Then $(d_3 - d_2 = d_3 - 2$. if $d_3 - 2 = d_2 $ then $d_3 = 4$. If $d_3 - 2 = d_1 $ then $d_3 = 3$

Powers of 2 seem to work, but not sure how to prove if other cases don't work.

It seems we can make some decent progress but I am stuck here..

Comment: What examples have you found?

Comment: @lulu power of twos work. but seemingly that's it.

Comment: No...$6$ works, and $20$.  I will post a partial solution below.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem much harder than the USAMTS. That question is asking for all SQUAREFREE integers satisfying this relation.

Comment: @N.S.  Well, thank you.  I was wondering about that.  My partial solution ran into the unknown question of the Fermat numbers, and I still haven't proven that my method is exhaustive.  With the new requirement, there is no difficulty.

Comment: @lulu I would not be surprise if the squarefree condition is put there to make the problem "solvable" :)

Comment: @N.S.  Oh, yes.  $\quad$  Like I say, the general one depends on knowing about the Fermat primes.  With the example of $42$, as produced by Oscar Lanzi, I think I'll delete my solution as it really isn't well aimed at the square free case.

Comment: @N.S. thank you... I edited the question, and while leaving this problem here, I will go give it a try myself first!

Comment: 42*43 works too

Comment: In general, if $n$ works and $n+1$ is prime, then $n(n+1)$ works. So from $2$ you get $6$ and from $6$ you get $42$ and from $42$ you get $43\cdot 42=1806.$ But $1807=13\cdot 139$ is not prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must have $d_1=1.$ So $d_2-1$ must be divisor less than $d_2$ so $d_2-1=1,$ or $d_2=2.$

In general, if $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ then let $d$ be the previous divisor. Then $p\not\mid d$ and $p-d$ must be a divisor of $n$ and likewise $\frac{n}{d}-\frac{n}{p}=\frac{(p-d)n}{pd}=(p-d)\frac{n}{pd}$ must be a divisor of $n.$

But we can show that $\gcd(p-d,pd)=1.$ So if $d\neq p-1$ then $(p-d)\frac{n}{pd}$ is not square free, so it cannot be a divisor of $n.$

So the only way for $p$ to be added is if $p-1$ is also a divisor.

In particular, we must start $1,2,3,\dots,$ and the next cannot be $5$ since $5\neq 3+1.$ So the next must be six, and the next value must be a prime, and the only prime can be $6+1=7.$

So we start $1,2,3,6,7,\dots,14,\dots, 21,\dots,42,\dots$ If there were any primes added to this in the $\dots,$ then the smallest such $p$ must have $p-1$ in $7,14,21,42.$ But the only option is $p=43,$ because $7+1,14+1,21+1$ are all non-prime.

So the sequence must start:

$$1,2,3,6,7,14, 21,42,\dots$$

We can stop at $n=42.$ Or we can continue with $p=43.$ But then we have that there is not prime $p$ so that $p-1=43d_1$ where $d_1\mid 42.$ So there can be no larger $n.$

So the only values are $n=1,2,6=2(2+1),42=6(6+1),1806=42(42+1).$

Comment: I slogged through what works, but you explained why it works. $+1$

Comment: It was pointed out to me that I had failed to take every possible set of divisors into account, and consequently left $n=2$ out of my answer. Technically, $n=1$ is not a solution to the question as posed as OP requires $n$ to have a minimum of two distinct divisors, if for no other reason than to obtain a difference which is able to divide $n$.

Comment: Can you elaborate why "$\gcd(p-d,pd)=1.$" and why "if $d\neq p-1$ then $(p-d)\frac{n}{pd}$ is not square free"

Comment: @MattFrank Show that $\gcd(p-d,p)=1$ and $\gcd(p-d,d)=1$ separately, Then since $\gcd(p,d)=1$ this allows you to say that $\gcd(p-d,pd)=1.$

Comment: For the second part, since $p-d\mid n$ and $pd\mid n,$ we can conclude that $(p-d)pd\mid n.$ But we know that $$(p-d)\frac n{pd}=(p-d)^2\frac n{pd(p-d)}$$ is a divisor of $n$

Comment: So $(p-d)^2$ is a factor of $n$. But $n$ square-free means $p-d=1,$ or equivalently, $d=p-1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you!

Comment: The number $1$ is dubious here because the problem statement seems to assume two or more divisors.  I would render the solution set $\{2,6,42,1806\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your progress as far as it goes is spot on. If $d_3=4$, $n$ is not square-free. So you are restricted to looking at $d_3=3$. In this case, $n$ is at least $6$, so $d_4=6$, and $n$ is either $6$ or a multiple of $6$. Any multiple of $6$ that is even or contains a factor of $3$ will not be square-free. So only certain odd multiples of $6$ can be considered.

$d_5-d_4$ must equal $1,2,3,6$, but even numbers and multiples of $3$ are forbidden, so $d_5-d_4=1$ and $d_5=7$, in which case $n$ is either $42$ or a multiple of $42$. In future steps, multiples of $7$ must be avoided to keep the resulting $n$ square-free.

$d_6-d_5$ must equal $1,2,3,6,7,14,21,42$, but even numbers and multiples of $3,7$ are forbidden, so $d_6-d_5=1$ and $d_6=43$, in which case $n$ is either $1806$ or a multiple of $1806$. In future steps, multiples of $43$ must be avoided to keep the resulting $n$ square-free.

$d_7-d_6$ must equal $1,2,3,6,7,14,21,42,43,86,129,258,301,602,903,1806$, but even numbers and multiples of $3,7,43$ are forbidden, so $d_7-d_6=1$ $d_7=1807$, in which case $n$ is $1806\cdot 1807$ or a multiple of $1806\cdot 1807$. Alas, $1807=13\cdot 139$, and $13$ is not in the list of factors, so the trail peters out here.

The possibilities for $n$ are $6,42,1806$

**BY EDIT:** Oscar Lanzi (in comments) points out that $n=2$ is a solution if the divisors consist entirely of $d_1=1,\ d_2=2$. Apologies for overlooking that as I started with OP's query on how to proceed based on possible values of $d_3$.

Comment: You have to show why $d_4\neq 5,$ right?

Comment: The real key is that if $p$ is a prime divisor of $n,$ then $p-1$ must be a divisor of $n.$

Comment: If $d_4=5$, then $n>6$, but $6\mid n$, so $10\mid n$ meaning $10-6=4\mid n$ and $n$ is not square=free, except if $7$ is an intervening divisor. But then, $70$ and $42$ are sequential divisors of $210$, and their difference $28$ is neither square-free nor a divisor of $210$. Seemed apparent, but you're right, I should have added it for completeness.

Comment: $10-6$ is a divisor only if $7$ is not. Why can’t the sequence start $1,2,3,5,7,10,\dots?$ There are lots of special cases unless you use some general result.

Comment: One minor error.  $n=2$ is not only an additional solution but also the base from which the others are built.  Please correct tovadmit that solution, thank you.